# Need help querying database by todays date while ignoring the time

Tags: hibernate, grails, jodatime

I have a grails project that uses hibernate to talk to a postgres db. I'm using the joda time plugin. I've been using their `DateTime` format `2013-01-25 22:28:55` to store dates. I need to know when something happened two weeks ago hince the variable `deadline`.

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime

Collection<PerformanceReview> outstandingSelfEvaluations(DateTime deadline) {
    Person.executeQuery("select pr from PerformanceReview as pr \
                    inner join pr.performanceReviewStatus as status \
                    where status.name in (:name) \
                    and pr.employeeEvaluation = null \
                    and pr.dateCreated = :deadline",
            [name: ['Open', 'New'], deadline: deadline])
}
```

main function

```
def incompleteSelfEvaluations(Integer days) {
    def deadline = LocalDate.now().minusDays(days)
    def performanceEvaluations = outstandingSelfEvaluations(deadline)

    performanceEvaluations.each { PerformanceReview pr ->
        sendSelfEvaluationReminderEmail(pr, evaluationDeadline)
    }
}
```

The only problem is, I don't know how to check for just the date while ignoring the time.

**Edit:** added all relevant code and removed an error message that wasn't useful to this particular problem

Comment: looks like your import package is different. Please correct this.

Comment: I removed that error message, it wasn't relevant to what I was attempting to achieve. And, as you said, I was using different import packages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may seem like a lot of noise but using the `DAY`, `MONTH`, and `YEAR` features of Hibernate works well. You can find out more in the [documentation](http://dev.anyframejava.org/docs.en/anyframe/plugin/hibernate/4.6.1/reference/html/ch06.html) about these features. This way you don't have to worry about passing additional information in and it's database independent.

```
Collection<PerformanceReview> outstandingSelfEvaluations(LocalDate deadline) {
    Person.executeQuery("select pr from PerformanceReview as pr \
                    inner join pr.performanceReviewStatus as status \
                    where status.name in (:name) \
                    and pr.employeeEvaluation = null \
                    and DAY(pr.dateCreated) = DAY(:deadline)
                    and MONTH(pr.dateCreated) = MONTH(:deadline)
                    and YEAR(pr.dateCreated) = YEAR(:deadline)",
            [name: ['Open', 'New'], deadline: deadline])
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is a simpler way, but one way to do it would be to use two parameters (one for start time and one for end time) and then use the `>=` and `<` operators in the query, e.g.:

```
...
and pr.dateCreated >= :startTime and pr.dateCreated < :endTime
```

Then in the calling code you set `startTime` to the deadline date at midnight, and you set `endTime` to the day after deadline at midnight.

Comment: not a bad idea, I will go with this if I'm unable to find a simpler solution.